# Inserting to closest element while drag and drop is not working

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I am currently in the process of building an HTML web page builder using the HTML Drag and Drop API. The builder consists of draggable elements and a canvas where these elements can be dropped. I have successfully implemented the ability to drag elements onto the canvas and rearrange them within it. However, I am currently facing a couple of challenges:

When dragging an element over the canvas, I want to determine if the drop target is a droppable container. If it is, the element should be dropped inside the container; otherwise, it should be dropped above or below the containers. Unfortunately, my current implementation is not achieving the desired behavior.

If I drop an inline element, such as a button, onto the canvas and then attempt to drag and drop another element next to it, the new element doesn't align perfectly with the button. Instead, it gets dropped slightly to the side. I would like to implement an algorithm that detects the closest element and drops the new element near it to ensure a seamless user experience.

Additionally, I would like to incorporate a visual drop indication when the user drags an element over the canvas. This feature aims to provide users with a clear visual cue about the potential drop location.

My goal is to create a user-friendly website builder, similar to Grape JS. Below is a snippet of my current code. Could you please offer guidance on resolving these issues and enhancing the overall functionality of the web page builder, including the addition of a drop indication?"

here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Website Builder</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      .elements-section {
        display: flex;
        gap: 1rem;
        padding: 1rem;
      }
      .element {
        padding: 1rem;
        border: 1px solid #eeeeee;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background: rgb(97, 173, 244);
        color: white;
        cursor: move;
      }
      #canvas-section {
        padding: 1rem;
        height: 80vh;
      }
      #canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        border: 2px solid blue;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="elements-section">
      <div
        draggable="true"
        data-tag="h1"
        data-droppable="false"
        class="element"
        id="element-h1"
      >
        H1
      </div>
      <div draggable="true" data-tag="p" class="element" id="element-p">P</div>
      <div
        draggable="true"
        data-tag="button"
        data-droppable="false"
        class="element"
        id="element-button"
      >
        Button
      </div>
      <div
        draggable="true"
        data-tag="div"
        data-droppable="true"
        class="element"
        id="element-div"
      >
        Div
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="canvas-section">
      <iframe id="canvas" data-droppable="true"></iframe>
    </div>

    <script>
      let currentDraggedElement;

      const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".element");
      elements.forEach((element) => {
        element.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
          const newCanvasElement = document.createElement(e.target.dataset.tag);
          newCanvasElement.classList.add("canvas-element");
          newCanvasElement.innerText = e.target.dataset.tag;
          newCanvasElement.style.background = "red";
          newCanvasElement.setAttribute(
            "data-droppable",
            e.target.dataset.droppable
          );
          newCanvasElement.draggable = true;
          newCanvasElement.addEventListener("dragstart", (e) => {
            currentDraggedElement = e.target;
          });
          newCanvasElement.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
            currentDraggedElement = null;
          });

          currentDraggedElement = newCanvasElement;
        });
        element.addEventListener("dragend", (e) => {
          currentDraggedElement = null;
        });
      });

      const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").contentDocument;

      canvas.body.setAttribute("data-droppable", "true");
      canvas.body.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => e.preventDefault());
      canvas.body.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        const isDroppable = JSON.parse(e.target.dataset.droppable);

        if (isDroppable) {
          e.target.appendChild(currentDraggedElement);
        } else {
          e.target.parentElement.insertBefore(currentDraggedElement, e.target);
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If I drop an inline element, such as a button, onto the canvas and then attempt to drag and drop another element next to it, the new element doesn't align perfectly with the button. Instead, it gets dropped slightly to the side. I would like to implement an algorithm that detects the closest element and drops the new element near it to ensure a seamless user experience.